# How can I solve y = (x+1)**3 -2 for x in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I'd like to solve `y = (x+1)**3 - 2` for `x` in sympy to find its inverse function.
I tried using `solve`, but I didn't get what I expected.

Here's what I wrote in IPython console in cmd (sympy 1.0 on Python 3.5.2):

```python
In [1]: from sympy import *
In [2]: x, y = symbols('x y')
In [3]: n = Eq(y,(x+1)**3 - 2)
In [4]: solve(n,x)
Out [4]: 
[-(-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(-27*y/2 + sqrt((-27*y - 54)**2)/2 - 27)**(1/3)/3 - 1,
 -(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(-27*y/2 + sqrt((-27*y - 54)**2)/2 - 27)**(1/3)/3 - 1,
 -(-27*y/2 + sqrt((-27*y - 54)**2)/2 - 27)**(1/3)/3 - 1]
```

I was looking at the last element in the list in `Out [4]`, but it doesn't equal `x = (y+2)**(1/3) - 1` (which I was expecting).
Why did sympy output the wrong result, and what can I do to make sympy output the solution I was looking for?

I tried using `solveset`, but I got the same results as using `solve`.

```python
In [13]: solveset(n,x)
Out[13]: {-(-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(-27*y/2 + sqrt((-27*y - 54)**2)/2 - 27)**(1/3)/
3 - 1, -(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(-27*y/2 + sqrt((-27*y - 54)**2)/2 - 27)**(1/3)/3 -
 1, -(-27*y/2 + sqrt((-27*y - 54)**2)/2 - 27)**(1/3)/3 - 1}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare that `x` and `y` are positive, then there is only one solution:

```
import sympy as sy
x, y = sy.symbols("x y", positive=True)
n = sy.Eq(y, (x+1)**3 - 2)
s = sy.solve(n, x)
print(s)
```

yields

```
[(y + 2)**(1/3) - 1]
```

Comment: This works (sounds odd though, the solution should work for all real numbers), but when I try to extend it to another polynomial equation like `n = Eq(y, (x+1)**5)`, I get an empty set. Do you know what I can do to get the x = y**(1/5) -1 I was expecting? (I can ask this in another question if I'm supposed to.)

Comment: @DragonautX: Sorry, I don't have a good answer to your general question.

Comment: That's okay. In the end, I can always do it by hand and work from there, or i can try another tool.

Answer (score 5):

Sympy gave you the correct result: your last result is equivalent to (y+2)**(1/3) - 1.

What you're looking for is `simplify`:

```
>>> from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, simplify
>>> x, y = symbols("x y")
>>> n = Eq(y, (x+1)**3 - 2)
>>> s = solve(n, x)
>>> simplify(s[2])
(y + 2)**(1/3) - 1
```

edit: Worked with sympy 0.7.6.1, after updating to 1.0 it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: How were you able to assign the Eq() to n without doing `x,y = symbols('x y')`? Also, I still can't get the simplified version you got. I get `-2**(2/3)*(-y + sqrt((y + 2)**2) - 2)**(1/3)/2 - 1`.

Comment: By forgetting to copy it, sorry. Well, try `for sol in s: print(simplify(sol))`; I believe the order is random.

Comment: I get the same result as @DragonautX. Using sympy version 1.0 on python 3.5.2

Comment: I'm on sympy 0.7.6.1, Python 3.5.2

Comment: I'm using the same version as @SethDifley. I'll add that in to my post. Maybe something changed between versions?

Comment: @DragonautX I just updated to sympy 1.0 and it doesn't work anymore. I'll try some things..